# Change Ownership of External Hard Drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, permissions, external-hdd, ownership

I recently bought an external hard drive on Ebay, I received it and plugged it into my laptop and when I tried moving files onto it, it refused me to drag them on. I looked into the properties of the drive and only user #99 in group 99 could edit settings and files on the drive. Is there any way that I can change this? I am running Ubuntu 13.4 by the way. Thanks to anybody that can :)

Answer (score 1):

Just reformat it by using **Disk Utility** from the dash

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `chown`.
Basically do this :

```
sudo chown -R /media/externalDriveName
```

Change `/media/externalDriveName` to whatever the mount point of the device is.